Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. due to Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener
I am trying to do a ./gradlew clean build in my flutter project. This is the error that was caught.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.                                                                                                                                                                             
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules common-24.8.0.aar -> jetified-common-24.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.8.0) and mapbox-android-core-2.0.1.aar -> jetified-mapbox-android-core-2.0.1-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules common-24.8.0.aar -> jetified-common-24.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.8.0) and mapbox-android-core-2.0.1.aar -> jetified-mapbox-android-core-2.0.1-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:2.0.1)

I added
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.mapbox.common:common:24.8.0'
    }
}

in gradle.build app root. But I don't think its working because the error still persists.
the pubspec for more info
name: mobile_drone_gis
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.2 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  badges: ^3.1.2
  
  circular_menu: ^2.0.1
  dio: ^5.7.0
  dji: ^1.0.13
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.2.1
  flutter_map: ^7.0.2
  flutter_map_cancellable_tile_provider: ^3.0.2
  flutter_map_geojson: ^1.0.8
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.8
  geojson_vi: ^2.2.5
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  latlong2: ^0.9.1

the conflicting dependency would probably be DJI. But please let me know if I made a mistake.

Can you share your pubspec.yaml? You might have two dependencies that are causing this error.

name: mobile_drone_gis
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0
environment:
sdk: '>=3.3.2 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
badges: ^3.1.2
circular_menu: ^2.0.1
dio: ^5.7.0
dji: ^1.0.13
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_dotenv: ^5.2.1
flutter_map: ^7.0.2
flutter_map_cancellable_tile_provider: ^3.0.2
flutter_map_geojson: ^1.0.8
fluttertoast: ^8.2.8
geojson_vi: ^2.2.5
geolocator: ^12.0.0
latlong2: ^0.9.1
the conflicting dependency would probably be DJI. But please let me know if I made a mistake.

This conflicting dependencies in your project involving Mapbox libraries. Specifically, the classes PermissionsListener and PermissionsManager are present in both com.mapbox.common:common and com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core. This conflict typically happens when two libraries depend on different versions of the same module
Modify your app/build.gradle to exclude one of the dependencies causing the conflict
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.common', module: 'common'
    }
}

Alternatively, exclude the specific module
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:2.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.common', module: 'common'
    }
}

If you want to force a specific version of the conflicting dependency, then only adjust your app/build.gradle
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.mapbox.common:common:24.8.0'
    }
}

After making the changes, run:
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build

if not works above solution then, try to follow installation step properly as per document

You have my deepest gratitude. Although it may seem trivial. It took days for me to fix configuring the gradle. My thanks

@KingGallant You're most welcome! I'm glad my answer helped resolve your issue. If you face any further challenges, feel free to ask. Wishing you smooth coding ahead!
